# Access the code of the R_igraph_minimum_size_separators in R

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to access the code of the `minimum.size.separators` function from `igraph` package from `R`. I tried everything I could using what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function), and only the following appears for me:

```
function (graph) 
{
    if (!is_igraph(graph)) {
        stop("Not a graph object")
    }
    on.exit(.Call("R_igraph_finalizer", PACKAGE = "igraph"))
    res <- .Call("R_igraph_minimum_size_separators", graph, PACKAGE = "igraph")
    if (igraph_opt("return.vs.es")) {
        for (i_ in seq_along(res)) {
            res[[i_]] <- create_vs(graph, res[[i_]])
        }
    }
    res
}
<environment: namespace:igraph>
```

In fact this is not the code that performs what the function does, but rather it is the code that calls `R_igraph_minimum_size_separators`, which I did not find its code. Does anyone know how to find the `R_igraph_minimum_size_separators` code?

Comment: the definition of that particular function call is located [here](https://github.com/cran/igraph/blob/5635d276ef6ec181f2d72bc8f3e423e854464c75/src/separators.c#L643) it is not written in R

Comment: From the website: http://igraph.org, there is a link to the Github repository, from there you can view the source code.  It may take some time to find the correct file.

Comment: Hey! I'm looking for R_igraph_finalizer and R_igraph_hub_score. Am I able to find these in the GitHub repository, too? The navigation isn't the easiest. Thank you in advance.